# I tried to make a sliding nav bar from the side, but when i open the nav bar, the button to close it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

/Buttons to other pages/
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #6E001C;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #F8F5EE;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/close button/
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: 28px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>

<img id ="logo" src="/templates/HR_LOGO.png">



<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Previous meetings</a>
  <a href="#">Create meetings</a>
  <a href="#">Classes</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("logo").style.marginLeft = "0px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0px";
  document.getElementById("logo").style.marginLeft = "0px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing the positions from positive to other option, though that hasn't worked and has only places the x button some where else. I think the the problem mainly stems from the fact of the z-index, because only after trying to get the logo on top of the nav bar instead of getting it under it did it stop working. Which is weird because i can press on the ones that would send me to a different page and the open nav button also still works, but when i go over the x button with my mouse it doesn't change the arrow to the finger(signaling that you cant click on it(since it doesnt do anything).

Comment: Where is the closeNav() function?

Comment: it's all the way at the bottom of the code

Comment: You have a number of issues here (some unrelated to your problem but issues nonetheless). 1) All content must be either inside the head or body elements. 2) You're using invalid comment syntax in your CSS. That could be disabling some of it. 3) Don't use inline styles. That goes unnoticed and makes debugging more difficult. 4) You should be using _one_ function to toggle your menu, and it should simply toggle a class on an element containing your menu. The styles your script applies should be in your CSS.

Comment: Please see [ask], then move your code into a demo snippet using the editor. Clean up the issues I mentioned so they're not distracting from the actual issues. Put your problem description _before_ your code, so we know what we're looking at.